# Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed | Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, pdf-generation

I got this error when I try to convert HTML to pdf with large files in ubuntu. I tried the same in my local(which is windows), it got successfully completed. I don't understand why this error is coming in ubuntu server. Please refer below code snippet

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: true,
          executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
          args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setContent(renderedTemplate); // Here I'm pushing the html content into puppeteer.
      const css = `
                @media print {
                    .new-page {
                        page-break-before: always;
                    }
                }
            `;
      await page.addStyleTag({ content: css });
      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true,
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        headerTemplate: headerTemplate,
        footerTemplate: footerTemplate,
        margin: { top: '100px', bottom: '100px', left: '15px', right: '15px' },
        timeout: 600000,
      }); // PDF conversion.
      await browser.close(); // Closing the connection.
```

I installed chrome as part of my docker execution. Please refer below

```
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
    && apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
    && rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
    && echo "Chrome: " && google-chrome --version
```

Note: I tried headless as `true` and `new`. Both cases, I got the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? It fails for me on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: hi, did you manage to fix it?